# NotMapped & Explicit Loading Or LazyLoading EF Core

Tags: lazy-loading, asp.net-core-2.0, repository-pattern, ef-core-2.2

I'm working on a `EF Core` API where few properties are to be `Explicitly` / `Lazy loaded`. But it is throwing me couple of exceptions when i try,

**Model:**

```
public int NationalityId { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public Country Nationality { get; set; }
```

**Repo:**

```
RepositoryContext.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Nationality).Load();
```

this throws me `"Property Nationality cannot be found on the entity User"`

Also tried `virtual` instead of `[NotMapped]` and this,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(x => x.Nationality);
```

when i remove the `"[NotMapped]"` attribute and try, i get the below error,

```
"Column name NationalityId1 cannot be found" ==> SQLException
```

The same happens for Lazy loading too - I use `ILazyLoader` and i tried like,

**Model:**

```
 [NotMapped]
        public Country Nationality
        {
            get => LazyLoader?.Load(this, ref _nationality);
            set => _nationality = value;
        }
```

Can someone help me to fix the issues and use both the data loading techniques ?

**Note: I'm using EFCore 2.2.4**

Comment: In order to be eager/explicit/lazy loadable (and in general usable in EF Core queries), the navigation property must be **included** in the model. i.e. don't use `[NotMapped]` or `Ignore`.

Comment: If not used, the column gets created in the table and the type of the column is custom type. How to handle that?

Comment: You need to find what is causing it (incorrect fluent mapping, FK / PK type mismatch etc.). Information from the post is not enough to tell you the exact problem and how to solve it. We need to see the other side of the relationship (`Country` class) as well as the fluent configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ignore/NotMap the related entity you should teach EF how this entities are related. As you are using DataAnottation Attributes. You can use `ForeignKeyAttribute`

```
[ForeignKey("Nationality")]
public int NationalityId { get; set; }

public Country Nationality { get; set; }
```